# if $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = l$ and $b\neq0$, then $\lim_{x \to o} \frac{f(bx)}{x} = bl$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, epsilon-delta

How to show USING an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument this:

If $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = l$ and $b\neq0$, then 
$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(bx)}{x} = bl$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{f(bx)}{x}=b\left(\frac{f(bx)}{bx}\right)$.

Comment: Please avoid posting problems just as assigned exercises.  Many Readers are eager to help you learn this material, but when you post an exercise without much evidence that you thought about it before posting, it is apt to be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: If I'd had any convincing and solid clue i'd write down it. But it was not the case.

Comment: @SamuelDíaz Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(x)}{x} = l$ means that for all $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta_{\epsilon} > 0$ so that for all $x; |x - 0| < \delta_{\epsilon}$ then $|\frac {f(x)}x - l| < \epsilon$.

So for $\frac {\epsilon}b > 0$ let $\delta_{\epsilon/b}$ be such that $| x- 0| < \delta_{\epsilon/b}$ implies $|\frac {f(x)}x - l| < \frac {\epsilon}{b}$.

Now let $\Delta = b*\delta_{\epsilon/b}$. Let $g(x) = \frac {f(x)}{x}$.

Then if $|x - 0| < \Delta$ then

$|x - 0| < b*\delta_{\epsilon/b}$.  And

$|\frac xb - 0| < \delta_{\epsilon/b}$. And

$|\frac {f(xb)}{xb} - l| < \frac {\epsilon}b$.  And

$|\frac {f(xb)}x-bl| < \epsilon$.  And

$|g(x) - bl| < \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(bx)}b = bl$.

So let $\delta_{\epsilon} = \Delta$ we have proven that for all $x; |x-0|<\delta_{epsilon}$ then $|\frac {f(bx)}{x} - bl| < \epsilon$.

SO by definition $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(xb)}x  = bl$.

Comment: I'm not completely convinced. I think your argument would work if we define $\Delta=b/(\delta_{\epsilon/b})$.  What do you think?

Comment: I think my argument works as it and having $|x - 0|< \frac b{d_{\epsilon/b}$ would imply $|\frac xb - 0|< \frac 1{\delta_{\epsilon_b}$ but from thereon out we are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = l$ we have

$$\left| \frac{f(x)}{x} - l\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{b} \quad \forall0<|x|<\delta$$

then

$$\left| \frac{f(bx)}{bx} - l\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{b}\quad \forall0<|bx|<\delta$$

and

$$\left| \frac{f(bx)}{x} - bl\right|<\epsilon \quad \forall0<|x|<\frac{\delta}{|b|}=\delta_1$$

Comment: Why is true the first line?

Comment: We want to prove the last and since for the existing limit we are free to fix whatever value for $\epsilon$ we take $\epsilon/b$ such that the limit for $f(bx)$ is proved.

Comment: I think you have to take $|b|$ instead of $b$ in $\frac{\epsilon}{b}$

Comment: Oh yes of course for the case b<0, thanks I fix!

Answer (score 2):

1)Let $\epsilon/|b| >0$ be given.

There is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$|y|<\delta$ implies

$|f(y)/y -l| < \epsilon/|b|$.

2) Set $y:=xb$ then :

$|y|=|xb| \lt \delta$  implies

$|f(y)/y-l| = |f(xb)/xb -l| =$

$ |1/b| |f(xb)/x -bl| \lt \epsilon/|b|$, or

$|f(xb)/x-bl| <  \epsilon.$